# May I use com.google.code prefix for my packages?

Tags: java

I have a hobby opne source Java project hosted at google code ([linkset](http://code.google.com/p/linkset/)).

May I use a prefix "**com.google.code.linkset**" as a package name for this project?

P.S.
I dont own "org.linkset" domain :( but i like the name :)

Comment: you can use whatever you want

Comment: @Boris: technically yes, but the idea is to use a domain that you "control" in order to avoid conflicts. Also: prefixing "com.google" implies ownership or at least endorsement by Google which may or may not be desired.

Comment: You might want to ask that in their forums: http://groups.google.com/group/google-code-hosting

Comment: I suggest using the `alt.alien.vampire.flonk.flonk.flonk` package name.

Comment: Jup, but this project is not owned by Google. I hope the will not sue me or something.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java package namespace for projects with no own domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895835/java-package-namespace-for-projects-with-no-own-domain)

Answer (score 3):

the name of your packages does not have to reflect the domain it's hosted at.

I think using com.google prefix will mislead your users into thinking the code was developed at google. don't do it unless you want to handle the backfire from your users when they realize it's not.

Comment: so perhaps something neutral like "org.opensource" ?

Comment: @lbownik: that's not neutral either. "opensource.org" is owned by the OSI.

Answer (score 3):

Since it would be misleading as Omry already mentioned, why not use `org.lbownik.util.linkset`?

Comment: This sounds reasonable since the possibility of someone registering such domain (lbownik - Lukas Bownik) is low. :)

Comment: By the way. Is there a possibility to register a domain like "lbownik.org" ane redirect it to "code.google.com/p/linkset" for free?

Comment: @lbownik: registering the domain almost always costs some money, but not a lot (I would be very wary of free offers). Redirecting is often free with the registration.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pretty much anything as a package name, provided that it respects the java spec (no keywords, not starting with a number ...)
But really you shouldn't unless you work at Google!

Answer (score 1):

If you name your package `com.google.code.linkset` it is possible that sometime in the future you will receive a "cease and desist" letter from Google's lawyers, citing your package name as infringing Google's registered trademarks.

**EDIT**

If you ever do receive such a letter, **do not ignore it** based on some amateur legal theorizing you read on some website.  If you want to resist the demand, you should first talk to a *professional* lawyer.

Comment: Which you can ignore, since trademark law protects trade names, and thus requires trade.

Comment: @MSalters you should know better than to offer unsound advice like that!!

Comment: Feel free to fleece your local lawyer. But it doesn't really take a professional to figure out that _trade_marks are related to _trade_. In particular, it relates to the exchange of _products and services_ in exchange for compensation.

Comment: @MSlater - actually, that is not the criteria.  The criteria is that you are using the mark for a commercial purpose.  And just hosting Google ads on your project page would be sufficient.  (I recall a recent case involving some XYZsucks.com site where this was an issue.)

Answer (score 0):

I think using com.google in your domain is a mistake, since it will imply that your project is owned/endorsed by Google. However, people have been using net.sourceforge in their Sourceforge-based projects for years, and this is really the same thing. I didn't think that was a good idea, either. So while you *can* use com.google in your domain, I think it's a bad idea and you should use something else.

Comment: net.sourceforge seems more reasonable to me than com.google, since sourceforge is a place to host code projects, while google is many other things besides.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a somewhat authorative domain-like name for the project, use something that obviously recognizable as **not a reversed domain**!

Technically, you should be able to use:

```
hobby.code.linkset
```

Have a look for example at junit and antlr. It's preferred to use a true hierarchical organization, but for a small hobby project you can start with a name such as this. You should be prepared to later on refactor your code to a real domain, once you have settled and the project grows.