# Java package namespace for projects with no own domain

Tags: java, namespaces

Is there a general rule-of-thumb on how to name package namespaces for open source projects with no own domain?

Namespaces should be unique, so domains were chosen to take care of that, but in the end it doesn't matter, as long as they are unique.

Now, if I have a project that is only hosted on github, is it okay to take

```
com.github.username.projectname
```

or is that rather frowned upon, because I use a domain that I don't really own?

Comment: Don't think that'd be a problem. Apache and Codehaus projects seem to do it that way.

Comment: your package name should not just be unique but it should be something that you own. suppose you have a email name@email.com you can use the package as com.email.name as if any conflict occurs, you are to win because you own the email. In short your package name should be unique and you should be able to prove that you own it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a number of com.google.code and projects with sourceforge in the package name, so that namespacing has plenty of precedent.

Comment: It will be funny when Google goes out of business and all those projects move somewhere else ... like Lycos..

Comment: @Perception Wouldn't really break anything, though. Not like, say, moving all Sun sites to Oracle and making specifications and forum posts practically impossible to find.

Answer (score 8):

In your example `com.github` has no direct relationship to your code. Where this code is stored (aka. hosted) does not matter and might change in the future. Therefore I propose a purely project specific name like

```
org.projectname
```

or even

```
projectname
```

since a package name does not need to be a domain name.

Oh, by the way: You will find precedence for nearly all and everything regarding naming conventions - not only for Java package names. But drastically speaking: In the history you can find precedence for every kind of murder also. Does that somehow make it acceptable only because someone else had done it before? I don't think so.

Comment: I would probably avoid org.projectname; the premise of the question asks about "no own domain name".  Since "projectname.org" is not owned by the project, that seems fairly misleading and might end up being an unpleasant legal battleground, or a possible source for confusion.

Comment: suppose someone else owns the domain projectname.org, he can fight with you legally

Answer (score 3):

It's fine. In general, just pick something "likely" to be unique, and project-specific.

Packages generally only collide when they're a library designed for consumption; if the packages are for use inside the project only, it matters much less.

Comment: The worry is more about using someone else's domain name rather than naming collisions, I believe.

Comment: @G_H Hence the first sentence of the answer.